# Trademark dispute resolution

Tags: legal

What was the resolution of the Monero trademark dispute described [here](https://forum.getmonero.org/20/general-discussion/320/monero-is-under-trademark-attack) and [here](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=583449.msg11764335#msg11764335).

If there has been no resolution what is the most recent update?

Is the company Moneero out of business? Their [former website](https://moneero.com/) is no longer operational and I can locate no recent information about them.

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Monero was represented by the incredible lawyers at the [Software Freedom Law Center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_Freedom_Law_Center), completely *pro bono*. They dealt with the Moneero counsel and indicated that we were all ready for a fight. Shortly thereafter [Moneero closed up shop](https://web.archive.org/web/20160304204839/http://moneero.com/), much to our great collective dismay:-P