# Does PayBee have a trademark?

Tags: legal, globee

When I searched for PayBee today, in addition to https://payb.ee/ which is run by [fluffypony](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/875/what-is-paybee-and-how-is-it-related-to-monero) I found another business with the domain https://www.paybee.org/.

After remembering this [prior incident](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/703/trademark-dispute-resolution) with Moneero, I wondered about PayBee

Does [PayBee](https://payb.ee/) have any trademark protection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in the US or EU jurisdictions. We're not bound by the name in any event:)